# How to create add columns (i.e., features) on a tf.Dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

**QUESTION**

Very often, one wants to enrich a raw dataset with derived features. I.e., new columns need to be created from preexisting ones. How does one do that in an *efficient* (and preferably *in-place*) way with a `tf.Dataset`?

PS: I tried to play around `tf.data.Dataset.map()`, `tf.data.Dataset.apply()`, and `tf.map()` but can't find the right syntax that does what I'm illustrating below.

**MINIMUM WORKING EXAMPLE**

To show what I want to do, I'll use pandas' `apply()`. For example, I'm trying to add a feature that is the length of the `embark_town` feature in the Titanic dataset.

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf # v. 2.0+

# Load the Titanic dataset
source = tf.keras.utils.get_file(
    "train.csv", 
    "https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-datasets/titanic/train.csv")

# Only select two features and one target for this example.
dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
    source, batch_size=5, label_name="survived", 
    select_columns=["embark_town", "age", "survived"],
    num_epochs=1, ignore_errors=True, shuffle=False)

# Add the derived feature `embark_town_len` via pandas.
batch, _ = next(iter(dataset))
batch = pd.DataFrame(batch)

print("Raw data:")
print(batch)

batch['embark_town_len'] = batch.apply(lambda x: len(x["embark_town"]), axis=1)

print("\nEnriched data:")
print(batch)
```

which produces

```
Raw data:
    age     embark_town
0  22.0  b'Southampton'
1  38.0    b'Cherbourg'
2  26.0  b'Southampton'
3  35.0  b'Southampton'
4  28.0   b'Queenstown'

Enriched data:
    age     embark_town  embark_town_len
0  22.0  b'Southampton'               11
1  38.0    b'Cherbourg'                9
2  26.0  b'Southampton'               11
3  35.0  b'Southampton'               11
4  28.0   b'Queenstown'               10
```

Note that although I'm using pandas' `apply()` here, what I'm really looking for is something that works directly on the whole `tf.Dataset`, not just a batch therein.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `tensorflow 2.0`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
cities_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(["Rome","Brussels"])
ages_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([5,7])
ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip((cities_ds, ages_ds)) 
ds = ds.map(lambda city, age: (city, age, tf.strings.length(city)))
for i in ds:
  print(i[0].numpy(), i[1].numpy(), i[2].numpy())
```

Comment: Thanks---this worked for this particular example of adding a column made up of the lengths of the strings, but what about an arbitrary function? E.g., what if I want to check if the city name contains the letter `o`. I replaced `tf.strings.length(city)` in your code with `o in city`, but got the error `OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over 'tf.Tensor' is not allowed: AutoGraph is disabled in this function.` (The idea is after all to be able to generate arbitrary derived features from pre-existing ones.)

Comment: `tf.Dataset` is designed for speed, so all code in `.map` must be a tensorflow graph (basically everything must be `tf.`. This way `tensorflow` knows how to parallelize your function. `AutoGraph` is the package that converts `python` code to a `ŧensorflow` code automatically. Some stuff he can't convert, like the `in` operator. So if you get such an error, you should Google something like `how to check membership in tensorflow`. So you can define any arbitrary function that can be converted by `AutoGraph`. It's not much yet, but the `tensorflow` guys are working hard to improve it!